# iOS Logger does not print to the Xcode console

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

I am trying to swap CocoaLumberjack for the iOS native Logger.  The only problem is that Logger messages are not logging to the Xcode Console.  In the WWDC20 video *Explore logging in Swift*, Ravi states at 09:02 **"If your app is launched from Xcode, you will see them in Xcode's console."**  However, I'm not seeing the messages.  Has anyone else tried this?

Using Xcode 13.4

Here is the code…

```
import os

extension Logger {

    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? ""

    public static func logDebug(message: String, category: String) {
        logger(category: category)
            .debug("\(message, privacy: .public)")
    }

    public static func logInfo(message: String, category: String) {
        logger(category: category)
            .info("\(message, privacy: .public)")
    }

    public static func logNotice(message: String, category: String) {
        logger(category: category)
            .notice("\(message, privacy: .public)")
    }

    public static func logError(message: String, category: String) {
        logger(category: category)
            .error("\(message, privacy: .public)")
    }

    private static func logger(category: String) -> Logger {
        Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: category)
    }
}
```

Here is the call site…

```
Logger.logNotice(message: "Firebase dispatch event -> \(name) || Parameters -> \(parameters.debugDescription)",
                 category: String(describing: FirebaseSDKDispatch.self))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work if I create a new app from scratch. I will need to investigate my commercial app further.

```
import os
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let log = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "app")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        log.debug("You better print in the Xcode console!")
    }
}
```